# Edit position of nodes in tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, mindmaps

I'm trying to make a `mindmap` with `tikz` but I want to add some fading (smooth transition between clear blue and dark blue) between the colour of the root node and his childrens.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, text width=3cm, align=flush center, 

every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!20,
                    level 1/.style={level distance=8cm,sibling angle=180},
                    level 2/.style={level distance=5cm,sibling angle=60}]
\node [concept color=blue!50]{Clasificacion de las calderas}
child{node{De acuerdo a}
child {node {Combustible empleado}}
child {node {Tipo de transferencia}}
child {node {Circulacion}}
child {node {Contenido de agua}}
child {node {Presion de horno}}
child {node {Configuracion}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, text width=3cm, align=flush center,
every node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!90,
                    level 1/.style={level distance=9cm,sibling angle=180,every child/.append style={concept color=blue!35}},
                    level 2/.style={level distance=6cm,sibling angle=60,,every child/.append style={concept color=blue!10}}]
\node {Clasificacion de las calderas}
child{node{De acuerdo a}
child {node {Combustible empleado}}
child {node {Tipo de transferencia}}
child {node {Circulacion}}
child {node {Contenido de agua}}
child {node {Presion de horno}}
child {node {Configuracion}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Trick here was to add

```
every child/.append style={concept color=blue!35}
```

to `level 1` and `level 2` styles.